# I can't import util.Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, libraries

I want to import calendar with "import java.util.Calendar;" but, my eclipse said nothing with red underline...

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Scanner is fine but Calendar, it says "The import java.util.Calendar conflicts with a type defined in the same file"

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Please post a small snippet of your code.  It will be easier to see what went wrong.

Comment: now you can delete it

Comment: So what do you think the error means?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the whole code which you have written in your Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't using `Calendar` when your class named the same `Calendar`, you need to rename your class.

Or you can create `MyCalenader` class for example, which extend `java.util.Calendar` and import this class.

Comment: Yes on rename, please no on extension of `Calendar`.

Comment: @Makoto Why 'no' on etension of `Calendar`?

Answer (score 0):

Is your class named `Calendar`?  That would cause this error.  To prevent that, the easiest way would be to re-name your class, or you could use `java.util.Calendar` in your code to refer to the external class without importing it.